# Tikzpicture in Beamer poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, math-mode, tikz-arrows, beamerposter

I'm trying to creative a commutative diagram in a beamer poster, but I cannot figure out why it's formatting incorrectly. The output builds as : [image]

When I'm trying to output it as:

[image]

Any reason as to why this would output incorrectly?

```
 \documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},8pt]{beamer}



    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
        \providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
        \usepackage{grffile}
        \mode<presentation>{\usetheme{I6pd2_centertitle}}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
        \usepackage{enumerate}
        \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
        \usepackage{pst-eucl}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{comment}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usepackage{subfigure}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows} 

     \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
    % change list indention level
    % \setdefaultleftmargin{3em}{}{}{}{}{}


    %\usepackage{snapshot} % will write a .dep file with all dependencies, allows for easy bundling

    \usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
    \newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!

    \listfiles

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \graphicspath{{figures/}}  


    \begin{document}
    %\fontsize{6pt}{6}\selectfont
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
        % ---------------------------------------------------------%
        % Set up a column 
        \hspace*{-2.6cm}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
          \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
            \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}  % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
              \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously

 \begin{block}{Maps Between Fuzzy Tangent Manifolds}

     \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
      \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins}, row sep={2em}] at (0,0) {
        \node(R) {$\mathscr{T}\M$}  ; & \node(S) {$\mathscr{T}\N$}; \\
        \node(R/I) {$\M$}; & \node (T) {$\N$};\\
      };
      \draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\pi_{\M}$};
      \draw[->] (R) -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\mathscr{T}f$};
      \draw[->] (S) -- (T) node[anchor=west] {$\pi_{\N}$};
      \draw[->] (R/I) -- (T) node[anchor=north] {$f$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{center}

    that is, $f \circ \pi_{\M} = \pi_{\N} \circ \mathscr{T}f$. \\
    Now suppose $f: \M \to \N$ and $g: \N \to \mathcal{H}$, then following diagram of fuzzy tangent manifolds is also commutative: 

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
    \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
            row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
    { \node(R)   {$\mathscr{T}\M$}  ; & \node(S) {$\mathscr{T}\mathcal{H}$}; \\
      \node(R/I) {$\mathscr{T}\N$};                   \\};
    \draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\mathscr{T}f$};
    \draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\mathscr{T}g$};
    \draw[->] (R)   -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\mathscr{T}(g \circ f)$};


      \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

          \end{block}  

        \end{minipage}
          \end{beamercolorbox}
        \end{column}
        % ---------------------------------------------------------%
        % end the column
      \end{columns}
      \vskip1ex

    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

It seems as though the arrows are having a scaling issue, although I'm not quite sure.

Updated code:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},8pt]{beamer}



        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows} 

     \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}


\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}

\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
    % change list indention level
    % \setdefaultleftmargin{3em}{}{}{}{}{}


    %\usepackage{snapshot} % will write a .dep file with all dependencies, allows for easy bundling

    \usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
    \newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!

    \listfiles

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \graphicspath{{figures/}}  


    \begin{document}
    %\fontsize{6pt}{6}\selectfont
    \begin{frame}

 \begin{block}{Maps Between Fuzzy Tangent Manifolds}

     \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
      \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins}, row sep={2em}] at (0,0) {
        \node(R) {$\mathscr{T}\M$}  ; & \node(S) {$\mathscr{T}\N$}; \\
        \node(R/I) {$\M$}; & \node (T) {$\N$};\\
      };
      \draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\pi_{\M}$};
      \draw[->] (R) -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\mathscr{T}f$};
      \draw[->] (S) -- (T) node[anchor=west] {$\pi_{\N}$};
      \draw[->] (R/I) -- (T) node[anchor=north] {$f$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{center}

    that is, $f \circ \pi_{\M} = \pi_{\N} \circ \mathscr{T}f$. \\
    Now suppose $f: \M \to \N$ and $g: \N \to \mathcal{H}$, then following diagram of fuzzy tangent manifolds is also commutative: 

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
    \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
            row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
    { \node(R)   {$\mathscr{T}\M$}  ; & \node(S) {$\mathscr{T}\mathcal{H}$}; \\
      \node(R/I) {$\mathscr{T}\N$};                   \\};
    \draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\mathscr{T}f$};
    \draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\mathscr{T}g$};
    \draw[->] (R)   -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\mathscr{T}(g \circ f)$};


      \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

          \end{block}  
-----------------------------------------------%
        % end the column
      \end{columns}


    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE.  Without the code, I suspect is is a scaling issue.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Added.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Please also include all your code starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` so that we know what packages (and especially `documentclass`) you're using. Thanks!

Comment: @darthbith Added preamble for document class

Comment: @R.Schumacher I think it's a scaling issue too, although I don't quite know how to fix it.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter The MWE you have does not compile and is in the wrong order.  You need to post the complete code that compiles to your output with scaling issues.   Your provided preamble could not have produced that input as you showed several packages which clash with beamer and prevent a compile.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Is what I just added enough? The complete code is rather long, so I'm trying my best not to post anything superfluous...

Comment: @AnthonyPeter  We don't need the entire code, but a minimum example which compiles which shows the problem.  See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that for discussion on MWE.  In essence build a small compilable tex file with the code for one of the diagrams in your orginal output.  Since you did get a compile.  In the code you have provided I note you are using beamer without any frames.  And you have themes and colors which are not available in CTAN. The scale option is discussed in the pgf manual. Use http://texdoc.net

Comment: @R.Schumacher I think I've fixed it.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Most of your packages are not meant to be used together. Please start an empty document put beamerposter with no theme whatsoever and the tikzpicture only! Then work your way up until the problem shows itself. You even have conflicting inputenc package calls. I managed to make the example work after 5 minutes of trial and error and still didn't arrive to the problem properly.

Comment: @percusse I'm really still not seeing the issue here... I've been trying for awhile, and this is very time sensitive for me; so any advice would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: @percusse I've been trying for hours to no avail

Comment: @percusse The code I've added outputs just the diagrams in a beamer slide.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comments, if you can just make the example more minimalistic then it becomes obvious that beamer doesn't like TikZ matrix `&` character. Hence it is not a scaling issue.

Then fixing it is pretty simple with `ampersand replacement`, please check the code reduction below I used to arrive at the problem.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Maps}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&] at (0,0) {
        \node(R)   {TM}; \& \node(S) {TN}; \\
        \node(R/I) {M} ; \& \node(T) {N} ; \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Learned something new, however as I tried to make a minimal working example I never saw the 'obvious' & issue.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Add a normal TikZ picture it works. Add a matrix it doesn't. And complains about next matrix cell macro. `&` is a nasty character... at least then you know this much is enough to arrive at the issue hence minimal.